# Shared jars in apache-tomcat 6.0.20

Tags: java, tomcat, java-web-start

I'm pretty new to JWS.

I have a web application ( several web services ) that I want to deploy using tomcat 6.0.20 on a linux system.

Everything's ok if I generate a .war file with all used libraries inside and put it in the webapps directory, but I want to have these jars shared, and the .war file itself is way too big.

First I tried the intuitive way - I created a link ( WEB-INF/lib ) to the directory containing the jars, but strangely it fails to deploy ( it starts if the directory is not a link ):

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:556)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:491)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1206)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

After that I created the $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib directory, and moved the jars there ( I've deleted the WEB-INF/lib ) and it still displays the same error - it seems tomcat isn't looking for the jars anywhere else than the WEB-INF/lib directory. But on the other hand - why would creating a symbolic link make any difference?

My CATALINA_HOME and JRE_HOME vars seems to be right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try putting the shared jar files in [$CATALINA_HOME/lib](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)?  It says that ". Normally, application classes should NOT be placed here" but sounds like you would actually want to in your case.

The $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib seems to be gone in 6.0 (it was there in 5.5).

Comment: Well that seems to work - I haven't even tried it before, as it was marked as deprecated in some tutorial.

Comment: It's been replaced by `shared.loader` property in `/conf/catalina.properties`. You can specify any local disk file system path(s) in there.

Answer (score 4):

To add a bit more detail on this.

- The metro project uses the shared class loader to make it possible to expose libraries to all webapps that you deploy.
- The metro project uses the endorsed library mechanism of Tomcat to update your standard java distribution

*Shared Class loader*

Shared resources are shared across all web applications and not used by Tomcat internal classes.If Tomcat 6 requires a shared library. Adjust $CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina.properties and set shared.loader=${catalina.home}/shared/lib/*.jar

*Endorsed libraries*

To update the java platform and incorporate a new version of a given library, included in the standard distribution, one can add the library to /lib/endorsed or set the system wide property java.endorsed.dirs If Tomcat 6 requires an endorsed library. Several strategies can be used to incorporate the required endorsed library

- add the given library to java-home/lib/endorsed
- set the Tomcat command line parameter -Djava.endorsed.dirs
- use the default directory $CATALINA_HOME/endorsed; see /bin/setclasspath.sh or /bin/setclasspath.bat
- set system wide parameter JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS

Comment: If CATALINA_HOME is different from CATALINA_BASE, then the file to edit is $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. To get behavior like Tomcat 5.5, set shared.loader=${catalina.base}/shared/classes,${catalina.base}/shared/lib/*.jar.

Answer (score 1):

In Tomcat 6, the content of `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` will be made available to the "*Common*" class loader (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html). The `shared/lib` directory that Tomcat 5.5 used to have no long exist.

However, I'd like to know what jars you are trying to put there exactly as the case of JAX-WS (or Metro) is "special". Also, what JDK are you using?

**Update:** As I said, the case of Metro is a bit special. To install it, copy webservices-rt.jar, webservices-tools.jar, webservices-extra.jar, webservices-extra-api.jar in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`. But webservices-api.jar and jsr173_api.jar should go in `$CATALINA_HOME/endorsed`. Actually, this is what the `metro-on-tomcat.xml` ant script provided in the metro distribution does (and I would recommend to mimic it).

Comment: We use Metro, Hibernate, MySQL, JNI for linux native functions and a few of our internal jars, and the JDK is 1.6.17.